SiC MOSFET short-circuit rating
Does the short-circuit withstand time on a MOSFET refer to the amount of time the transistor is operating at I=V_source*R_ds(on)?
I am trying to determine the best way to disconnect from an 800VDC power supply that should supply ~6000A for 0.2 seconds.
My initial thought was to use 100 SiC Transistors (Infineon IMZA120R014M1H's) connected in parallel to manage this current; however, the short circuit withstand time is 3us.
I will have a 20A 1kVDC slow-blow fuse connected to each drain.
I am also considering adding some inline resistance to the fuses to also limit them to 127A each, which is the max continuous rated current of each transistor (limited by the max virtual junction temperature of 175C).
Are these steps enough to prevent these transistors from going into thermal runaway?

If you could include more details (does the voltage need to remain at 800V, what is this for, etc.), we could give you better suggestions. Nevertheless, I will write an answer with insufficient info.

To your first question, I would answer "Yes".
Personally, at such high surge currents for such a long time, I would rather use an SCR because its surge current is MUCH higher and allowed for MUCH longer time than for any other controllable semiconductor switch.
The main issue with it is the lack of turn-off control.
You could solve this by charging up a large bank of capacitors calculated to give you that current surge for that much time, then discharging them through a bank of parallel SCRs with current-balancing resistances on each.
Since I don't your specific load nor its specific purpose, I can't help you with the calculations.
Just to give you an example of an SCR capability, here is one rated for 1200V and 100A (IXYS CLA100E1200HB datasheet):

As you can see, the surge current rating is at least 4 times higher than for an SiC MOSFET, and the surge time is 10ms which is over 3000 times longer!
You also have the "fusing" rating which would be the current and time at which the SCR would be "fused" (basically melted inside instantly), and this rating is an additional almost 6 times higher, which would give you the absolute peak current rating (before fusing) almost 24 times higher than an SiC!!
An SCR would also be cheaper than an SiC MOSFET.

Edin Fifić - Hi, Please remember that to comply with the site rule on referencing, you must link back to the source of copied material from other sites - that includes datasheets or anything else. (FYI, although it doesn't apply here, there are additional requirements if copying someone else's material from Stack Exchange, as the specific CC BY-SA license imposes additional obligations when copying - see here for explanation & examples.) Please can you edit this post to add the required reference for that copied material. TY

@SamGibson Thank you, I completely forgot to do that. I will edit to include the related information.

@EdinFifić thank you for your response. Our application is to simulate arc damage from a power feeder short. Our power supply is 62 marine batteries connected in series with a 163mF capacitor bank, which is connected in parallel to the marine battery bank.
We have considered SCR's but the lead time associated with heat sinks and other accessories is fairly high and expensive. We also need a fast response time on the circuit opening, which is what led me to SiC's.

@C-LEC If you include all those detailed requirements, along with a schematic, sketch, drawing or an image of your setup, it will help all of us here give you an answer that better suits your needs.

This would work, make sure when you parallel mosfets that you also add some series resistance on the order of RDSon. This usually can be done with proper PCB routing.
Why? Because RDSon can vary from fet to fet and you can easily reach an over current condition since one device could reach thermal runaway if it receives the bulk of the current.
You can usually provide this kind of resistance with trace resistance on a PCB. Also making sure that correct layout so all devices see the same current/voltage is necessary and parasitics matter.

Thank you for your answer. The R_ds(on) of the transistor is 14mOhms, which seems too low to add in with . If I add in R=V_source/I_ddc, would that be acceptable?
